# Kendo Grid in Bootstrap 2 or 3 Modal - IE Filters do not work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Please check this out in IE (boot v2):   http://jsbin.com/emuqazEz/22
Here is bootstrap 3 version: http://jsbin.com/emuqazEz/31

Here is the editable version: http://jsbin.com/emuqazEz/22/edit

The filters do not work at all in any version of IE I have tested.  It works fine however in Chrome or Firefox.

Here is are the column settings and the datasource:

```
columnsettings = [
        "ProductName",
        {
                field: "UnitPrice",
                title: "Unit Price",
                format: "{0:c}",
                width: "130px"
        },
        {
                field: "UnitsInStock",
                title: "Units In Stock",
                width: "130px"
        },
        {
                field: "Discontinued",
                width: "130px"
        }
];

var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
     data: products,
     schema: {
              model: {
                      id: "uid",
                      fields: {
                        ProductName: { type: "string" },
                        UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
                      }
              }
      },
      sort: {
              field: "",
              dir: "desc"
      },
      pageSize: 50
});
```

Comment: the button in your demo doesn't do anything

Comment: When it's in edit mode, it doesn't work.  You have to visit the top link in order for the button to work it's the one that doesn't have the html/css/javascript windows available.

Comment: looks like the modal is messing with the events, possibly because the filter elements are not inside the modal element and it thinks they shouldn't receive focus; no idea why this is IE-specific though, that might take a long time to figure out / debug; have you tried to reproduce this with bootstrap 3?

Comment: Just made a bootstrap 3 version.  You have to hit the refresh button on the grid to get it to not look wonky.

Comment: guess that didn't help... I don't see any obvious problems with the code, and the next step would probably to take a look at the events the modal is registering; you could try talking to telerik about it since they make efforts to stay compatible with bootstrap; apart from that: have you considered using a modal kendo window instead?

Comment: Even I'm having the same issue. If anybody has any solution to this, please let us know.

Answer (score 3):

here is what resolves my issue with this:

For bootstrap 3.0

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   $(document).off('focusin.modal');
  })
```

for other lower version as provided by telerik

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
  $(document).off('focusin.modal');
});
```

Comment: Working Fine. Thanks :)